# Getting back a permalink from custom url

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules, plugins-url

okay i have made my own rewrite rule, with the add_rewrite_rule function in wordpress to get a custom url, for an plugin page.

```
add_action( 'init', function() {

  add_rewrite_rule( 'login/?$', 'index.php?function=login', 'top' );
  add_rewrite_rule( 'login/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?function=login&id=$matches[1]', 'top' );

});

add_filter( 'query_vars', function($query_vars) {

  $query_vars[] = 'function';
  $query_vars[] = 'id';
  return $query_vars;

});
```

This works great and i can visit the page [domainname.com]/login to visit the page. Now the problem how do i best get a propper permalink for this page, one that works both with rewrite rules turned on, and off.

I tried using the get_permalink() function, and that works with pages, post on other stuff, but is there a function working in similar fashion that can get custom url's like this?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no permalink. Because it's a bespoke URL there's nothing to latch on to. You'd need to generate such a function yourself from scratch.

Luckily, your URL is just the word `login/` with an ID on the end, so when you need a URL, just write out `login/` and put the ID on the end. Wrap it in a call to `site_url` to change it from a relative path to an absolute path.

For the non-pretty version, just take the `'index.php?function=login&id=$matches[1]'` and swap `$matches[1]` for the ID you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and yeah that would work. but how would go around to make a function that instead would give a more "beautiful" url as the one you get from the get_permalink function

Comment: Pretty much the same method, substitution, the only magic part of this was `site_url` which takes `bananas` and turns it into `example.com/bananas` where `example.com` is the root URL of the site, `site_url` isn't even a part of the rewrite rules API. Everything else is just joining up strings, beginner level PHP